# Android: Solution for the device not compatible with the Google Play Store

Tags: android

I have Android mobile application. It given error with same android version with different phone models.

I need run my application for any device with out any compatible issue.
Below is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smartmetro.prime"
    android:versionCode="17"
    android:versionName="5.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        android:minSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
        android:required="true" />
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LauncherAppregisterMenuActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       ......
</manifest>
```

Please help me resolve **Device not compatible** problem

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I'm getting a "Device not compatible" error message in Google Play Store.

Comment: Play store? What?

Comment: Try to download via google play stores I'm getting a "Device not compatible" error message

Comment: Wait, I thought that you're the developer.

Comment: Yes i am the developer. 
Try to download via google play stores I'm getting a "Device not compatible" error message so need way do develop this app for working any devices

Comment: Then why are you trying to download from play store? Anyway it should be because the devices are not compatible.

Comment: Anyway it should be because of the nfc

Comment: My customer need to download this application via google play.so i removed NFC part because no need NFC for this application.but i check with NFC enable phone too result is same

Answer (score 0):

Not all devices have NFC, and while it is required, some devices won't run your app.

Comment: Thank you actually this application no need NFC i removed it.so it will work fine?

Comment: I don't know, try it.

Comment: Thank you.I did try with NFC enable phone too but result is same what are the other reasons can be?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="26"
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

Comment: Check the other permissions and features.